# What day of the week dose the week start with?

Tags: swift, date, calendar

Maybe I'm overthinking this. I want to send a local notification every Monday at 9am until some condition is met. I know this can be done by setting the `weekday` and `hour` components of a `DateComponents`. The problem I'm having is the value would I pass to `weekday` depends on the `Calendar` the `DateComponents` is using. Which if I understand correctly depends on the user's settings. For instance if the user's calendar week starts on a Sunday I would pass a 1 to `weekday` but if the week starts on a Saturday I would pass 2.

My question is how do I account for things like timezone, daylight savings, and week start day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weekday units are the number go 1 through 7, where 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday... And this won't never change.

When user changes setting, only the `calendar.firstWeekday` will change.

E.g. if the user's calendar week starts on Sunday, `firstWeekday = 1` else if start on Monday, `firstWeekday = 2`

Comment: ok good so I was over thinking it. Thank you.